# How can I install Docker in a Debian Chroot?

Tags: debian, docker, dependencies

I have a **Raspberry Pi 2** running **Raspian** (Debian 9 Stretch Arm). I want to create a Chroot environment of pure Debian Stretch, and install Docker there. I follow all the proper instructions from here: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian

When it comes time to install **docker-ce**, Aptitude says I'm missing some libraries (like libc6), but I believe the libraries are there and not being recognized. This would seem a to be very simple process, but I'm hitting a giant barrier.

I recorded a video of the install 
https://youtu.be/wMmZGxZOBbs

Here are the commands I executed (all ran as root):

```
mkdir d
debootstrap stretch d
mount -B /dev d/dev
mount -B /dev/pts d/dev/pts
mount -B /proc d/proc
mount -B /sys d/sys
chroot d /bin/bash
```

chroot'd

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list # add contrib and non-free
apt-get update
apt-get install aptitude
apt-get install bash-completion
apt-get install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg2 \
    software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=armhf] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
apt-get update
apt-get install docker-ce # Fails, says package unavailable
aptitude # Try to install docker in aptitude shows missings libraries
```

[image: Aptitude Error Screen]

## UPDATE:

When running the convenience script, I receive this output:

```
root@pi2:/# curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
root@pi2:/# sh get-docker.sh
# Executing docker install script, commit: 4957679
+ sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
+ sh -c apt-get install -y -qq apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl >/dev/null
+ sh -c curl -fsSL "https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg" | apt-key add -qq - >/dev/null
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
+ sh -c echo "deb [arch=armel] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch edge" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
+ sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
+ sh -c apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends docker-ce >/dev/null
E: Unable to locate package docker-ce
```

Running `apt-get update` shows that the repository "doesn't support architecture 'armel'".

## UPDATE2

Thanks to the answer from AB, it may not entirely solve the problem, but I'm definitely making great progress.

```
# ### Architecture Output from Debian Chroot
# dpkg --print-architecture
    armel
```

and

```
# ### Architecture Output from Raspian
# dpkg --print-architecture
    armhf
# lsb_release -cs # My system is up to date
    stretch
# debootstrap --arch=armhf stetch d
E: No such script: /usr/share/debootstrap/scripts/stetch
```

## UPDATE3

I found that it's possible to install Debian architechture Armhf by using the following command.

```
# debootstrap --foreign --arch=armhf stretch dir
```

## UPDATE4 SOLUTION

I successfully installed docker by forcing Debian to install as architecture armhf. Here are the steps I used to install Debian as architecture armhf.

```
mkdir d
debootstrap --foreign --arch=armhf stretch d
cat /etc/resolv.conf > d/etc/resolv.conf
chroot d /bin/bash
./debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
apt-get clean
```

After that, I follow the process of installing docker on Debian as normal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I added all the commands I used in the video.

Comment: Your video is showing `armel` architecture while Docker is available for `armhf` architecture.

Comment: That's a good point to consider. I know that the Pi2 isn't 64bit, so I assumed that the builds for armhf just meant some generic 32bit arm build? I may have to investigate into this more. Thank you!

Comment: Well thinking a bit more, I wonder why there's armel around here. It shouldn't even be there at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: you cannot install Docker's `docker-ce` package on `armel` architecture, but your system, being a Rasberry Pi 2, should be running `armhf` anyway, so there's something wrong in your setup.

Docker's [requirements for Debian](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/#os-requirements):

> ### OS requirements
>
> To install Docker CE, you need the 64-bit version of one of these
>   Debian or Raspbian versions:
>
> - Buster 10
> - Stretch 9 (stable) / Raspbian Stretch
>
> Docker CE is supported on `x86_64` (or `amd64`), `armhf`, and `arm64`
>   architectures.
>   on your system
>   The text is a bit misleading, since `armhf` is supported and 32 bits. Anyway, as your system is using the [`armel` architecture and not the `armhf`](https://www.debian.org/ports/arm/#status), there is no package available from docker.com. That is why whatever you try, you won't be able to follow their guide and install Docker.

What you can check first:

- Verify if your system (outside of chroot) is using `armel` or `armhf` with `dpkg --print-architecture`. If the answer is `armhf` then your `debootstrap` command went wrong and you should try again with the `--arch=armhf` option. **UPDATE**: that was it for OP, but it appears `--foreign` was also needed along, so this command made it:

  ```
  debootstrap --foreign --arch=armhf stretch d
  ```
- **UPDATE**: verify that the *kernel* is also an `armhf` kernel. Does it say `armv7`-something (probably `armv7l`) somewhere? or only `arm` or `armv6`-something ? It's possible that only the kernel isn't the correct one. If that's not an armv7 one you should consider changing it. Else this is an unexplainable bug with `debootstrap`, since I couldn't reproduce it on an other `armhf` platform.

---

Historical ideas to work around this issue below:

- Check if your hardware supports `armhf`, and reinstall it using `armhf` instead of `armel`. [Wikipedia tells the CPU for a Raspberry Pi 2 is at least an ARM Cortex-A7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Processor) so suitable for `armhf` as this (outdated) [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi#Raspberry_Pi_2) page and its [link to a Debian developper's blog](http://sjoerd.luon.net/posts/2015/02/debian-jessie-on-rpi2/) confirm. The [raspbian repository](https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/main/) provides *only* `armhf` not `armel`. So there's no reason `armel` should be seen at all and it's quite puzzling.

What else can ***perhaps***, but not easily anyway, be done else:

- an other solution, out of scope for its difficulty here, if it does support `armhf`, would be to complete the missing multi-arch libraries required to install Docker.
- Debian does ship for the as-of-now-unreleased future Debian 10 the equivalent [`docker.io`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/docker.io) package, available for `armel` (but it tells: "Using docker.io on non-amd64 hosts is not supported at this time"). So one can imagine that when Raspbian follows, this package can become available. Don't expect bleeding edge versions anyway.
- It's probably possible to rebuild from sources those Docker packages for the `armel` architecture. This requires anyway knowledge you probably don't have yet.

Even if you get it installed on `armel` please consider that anything you'll try to pull from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) will be incompatible: if Docker doesn't provide `armel` chances are there will be no `armel` ecosystem at all.

Comment: noticed that there's no reason armel should be running anywhere in the first place on a Raspberry Pi 2, so adjusted my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot AB. I have updated my post to reflect your answer.

Comment: Heh, so if my answer was the solution, you should mark it as accepted. Now the behaviour of debootstrap is strange. I tested the same on an Debian stretch (pure Debian, not Raspbian) `armhf` Odroid device, and debootstrap chose `armhf`. Anyway, I'll update my answer to add `--foreign` if that's also needed. **last question** what is giving `uname -a` ? Maybe your whole system is installed with `armhf` except the kernel?